# Problem on parallel transport

Tags: differential-geometry

I have the following doubt :

Let $R^n$ be equipped with an affine connection(not necessarily usual).Can we show that parallel translation of a tangent vector along any curve $\alpha$(t) from p to q is usual parallel translation".

Thanks in advance..

Comment: That certainly isn't true for a general affine connection.

Comment: @Ted Shifrin: actually i am trying to see whether an operator D satisfying four properties characterize connection on a manifold.for that purpose,i try to take M=$R^n$ and then see whether an operator D satisfying the four properties of affine connection gives me the usual connection on R^n,but for that we must get christoffel symbols zero.Is it sufficient to show that any parallel transport along a curve $\alpha$ (t) from point p to q wrt connection D is same as usual connection on D?

Comment: No, if you use different coordinates, the Christoffel symbols for the *usual* connection may be nonzero.